# Python: Creating multiple unique passwords

Tags: python, loops, passwords, unique

I am trying to create a script that generates X amount of random passwords. I have got the password generation part sorted for 1 case, but when I try and add 2 or more, it generates the same password for all cases. The code and result are below:

```
import string
import secrets

def random_secure_string(stringLength):
    secureStr = ''.join((secrets.choice(string.ascii_lowercase + string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits + string.punctuation) for i in range(stringLength)))
    return secureStr

Entities = ["MM","OO"]

Password = [random_secure_string(10)]

for x in Entities:
    for y in Password:
      print(x + ' ' + '=' + ' ' + y)
```

This returns the following

[image]

Can anyone help in generating a unique password for MM and a unique password for OO?
Thank you

Comment: You have created only one password, call the same function for generating some new passwords.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

separate call of `random_secure_string` should help.

```
Password = [random_secure_string(10), random_secure_string(10)]
```

I would prefer to generate passwords explicitly inside the loop

```
Entities = ["MM","OO"]

for x in Entities:

    print(x + ' ' + '=' + ' ' + random_secure_string(10))
```

Answer (score 1):

As I commented above, you are calling password generator function just one time. You can generate different passwords at each run.

That would be what you are looking for:

```py
import string
import secrets

def random_secure_string(stringLength):
    secureStr = ''.join((secrets.choice(string.ascii_lowercase + string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits + string.punctuation) for i in range(stringLength)))
    return secureStr

entities = ["MM","OO"]

# generate 2 passwords
passwords = [random_secure_string(10),random_secure_string(10)]

for (i, entity) in enumerate(entities):
    print(entity + ' ' + '=' + ' ' + passwords[i])
```